userChrome styles not applied in Thunderbird
I would like to style the Calendar inside Thunderbird (115.11.1 on MacOS) without using any extensions/add-ons. Specifically, I would like to modify the looks of recurring events. I enabled userChrome.css (toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets) and the “has:” selector (layout.css.has-selector.enabled). In my userChrome.css, I added styles:
li:has([alt*="Recurring"]) { background-color:grey !important; padding:1rem !important; }
li:has(*[alt*="Recurring"]) { background-color:yellow !important; padding:1rem !important; }

Unfortunately, this seems to have no effect upon restarting Thunderbird. However, when I open Developer Toolbox (Tools > Developer Toolbox > Developer Toolbox > Inspector tab) suddenly everything works and the stylesheets are applied, but only until Thunderbird is shut down. Other custome styles in Calendar seem to work ok.
Is this intended behavior or a bug? Can you let me know if it replicates with your Thunderbird?

Enable Custom Stylesheets in Thunderbird:
Open Thunderbird and go to Settings > General
Scroll down to Config Editor and click Open Config Editor.
Search for toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets.
Set this preference to true by double-clicking it.
And then put in userChrome.css (exactly the same spelling) and put in your thunder thunderbird/<your profile>/chrome.
If there is no directory chrome, create it, and put your userChrome.css into that directory.
Restart.
Voila!
